# Issues with Javascript functions in vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a function to authorize the user, so the user has restrictions on certain components. The function works well with the `'beforeEnter'` navigation-guard. How to use/write the same function in the router beforeEach router-guard?

I tried writing the function in beforeEach but the javascript functions (forEach, includes,..) are not working in the `router.beforeEach`.

This is the function to authorize

```
function authorizeUser(to) {
  const currentUser = store.getters["auth/isCurrentUser"];
  console.log(currentUser);
  currentUser.teams.forEach((team) => {
    const validPermissions = team.permissions.filter((item) => { return to.meta.neededPermissions.includes(item.permissionType); }); //returns array of objects
    const mappedValidPermissions = validPermissions.map((item) => { return item.permissionType;  });// returns array with permissionType
    // returned matched permissions
    console.log(
      JSON.stringify(to.meta.neededPermissions),
      JSON.stringify(mappedValidPermissions),  
    );
    if (!to.meta.neededPermissions.every(i=>mappedValidPermissions.includes(i))) {
      router.push({ path: "/:notFound(.*)" });     
    }  
  });
}
```

This is the `router.beforeEach` nav-guard-

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { 
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.getters["auth/isLoggedIn"]) {
    next({
      name: "Authentication",
      params: {
        desiredRoute: to.fullPath,
      },
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

How to utilize the above function and `if condition` in beforeEach, so that I can check each router link before giving access?

Answer (score 0):

What version of vue-router are you using. The [current version's signature](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) of `beforeEach` changed. Instead of calling `next`, you would optionally return either `false` or a route location object.

Comment: Thank you. I am using v4, but how to use the above function and condition in the router.beforeEach?